# combine 4 video with delay side by side using ffmpeg

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion, webrtc

I have at least 4 video from video conference crated by `meetecho/janus-gateway`
Janus create two mjr video and audio file for each user, first i merged them into one webm file, then convert all to 500*500 videos.
Now i'm trying to combine these videos like mosaic and found this code:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.webm -i 2.webm -i 3.webm -i 4.webm \
-speed 8 -deadline realtime -filter_complex "[0]pad=2*iw:2*ih[l]; \
[1]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+428/TB[1v]; [l][1v]overlay=x=W/2[a]; \
[2]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+439/TB[2v]; [a][2v]overlay=y=H/2[b]; \
[3]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS+514/TB[3v]; [b][3v]overlay=y=H/2:x=W/2[v]; \
[1]adelay=428372|428372[1a]; \
[2]adelay=439999|439999[2a]; \
[3]adelay=514589|514589[3a]; \
[0][1a][2a][3a]amix=inputs=4[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" merged.webm
```

I calculated the delayed times from created dateTime of each file, related to the first video.

my problmes:

1. This code is not working! after minutes of console freezing, it shows this line:

   Killed   29 fps=0.1 q=0.0 size=       1kB time=00:04:30.07 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s speed=0.896x
2. I didn't find out the meaning of letters before and after overlay, [1v][2v][3v][l][a][b][v]...

Comment: Show the complete log from the command.

Comment: @llogan , I checked my memory during executing this command, and found out console freezing is because of memory deficiency. It takes about 4GB memory! and then crash

Comment: Exactly. The "killed" line in the output means that something is terminating the process. and a look at your logs will probably say that it's the system OOM killer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using overlaying multiple times, try to use the "xstack" filter with all your video tracks, you can first delay all your inputs, then pipe them to xstack and make your own layout.

[There is an exemple of how to use piping with xstack to make a mosaic here.](https://superuser.com/questions/1616750/ffmpeg-interpret-input-size)

the meaning of the symbols between [ and ] are just a name/id to identify your tracks.

If a filter like "scale" is given one input and you want to process its output with another filter you can do it like this:

```
-filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920:1080[video_yourscaledoutput];[video_yourscaledoutput]your_next_filter=args[video_finaloutput]" -map "[video_finaloutput]" your_final_file.mp4
```

`[0:v]` here is an ID to the video track of your first input stream you can name the rest the way you want :)

Comment: thanks @Karu for the edit ! I'm fairly new and I will try to format my answers this way next time :)