# ffmpeg: interpret input size?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm sorry this is a bit of an open question, but: I have many square clips I make splitscreens with via ffmpeg xstacks. Problem is, half of my videos are 480x480, the other half 240x240 pixels. Now, before i convert one half to match the other I'm wondering: Is there maybe some way to tell xstacks to "interpret" a video as being of size x? Or like, in a separate pass, write some metadata to the files so they get interpreted as being of a different size? Or is there some other clever way of dealing with these kind of things? (It's over 100k clips, so...)

Comment: What do you want the end result to be when one input is 240x240 and the other is 480x480?

Comment: well depends. but for this use case i want to just treat the 480x480 clips as 240x240 (so scale them down). this is what otherwise i would do beforehand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can maybe scale all of your inputs down to 240x240 and then stack every sample at this size :

`ffmpeg -i .\inputfile_240-1.mp4 -i .\inputfile_240-2.mp4 -i .\inputfile_480-1.mp4 -i .\inputfile_480-2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=240:240[v0];[1:v]scale=240:240[v1];[2:v]scale=240:240[v2];[3:v]scale=240:240[v3];[v0][v1][v2][v3]xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|0_h0|w0_0|w0_h0[out]" -map "[out]" result.mp4`

adjust your layout to match what you want.

(maybe add flags to your scale filter depending on what you're doing to your files eg. upscale or downscale)

Comment: interesting, this sounds very promising! i'll try this and will report! thanks for your help!!

Comment: please ! glad if I can help any other way :)